# C# WebView crashes in metro

Tags: c#, webview, crash, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

So I have a webview I'm using the display links from reddit.
Some of the work fine, however other links seem to crash my application.

"http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-25663495"

Somebody said it could be script errors on the webpage. However I'm not sure how I can handle these errors and make the pages work.
Any ideas?

Here is the method where I fill the WebView

```
    private void topicsListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // WebView1.Source = new System.Uri("http://www.reddit.com");
        SetCorrectUrl();

        Page.Topic topic = pTopics[topicsListView.SelectedIndex];

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(topic.linkExternal) &&  !topic.linkExternal.Contains("www.reddit.com"))
        {
            WebView1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            WebView1.Source = new System.Uri(topic.linkExternal);

            //WebView1.Navigate(new System.Uri(topic.linkExternal));
            OriginalTopicBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(topic.text))
        {
            SetOriginalPost(topicsListView.SelectedIndex);
            originalPostTextBox.Text = topic.text;

            OriginalTopicBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            WebView1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }     
    }
```

Comment: @DGibbs I uploaded the method I use to fill the webview

Comment: Have you stepped through this? Which line does the error fall on?

Comment: @DGibbs I have debugged it yeah. It doesn't fail on a line, it gets through the method. It fails afterwards. It doesn't give a proper error in the debugger, it says there is no debugger attached for the type of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very common annoyance with WinRT 8.1 WebView.

You can disable this behavior by going to Debug > Options and Settings > Debugging > Just-In-Time and unchecking "Script".

Comment: Thanks for that Will it cause an error when the application is compiled and not running in Visual Studio?

Comment: No, that won't cause errors at all. This is just debugging behavior. I think it disappears even if you try to build release and start in VS.

Comment: Hi, but this solution didn't worked for me. Is there something else I am missing?